# Allow only a message in a chat discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a only allowed message in a chat. The code I tried deletes every message even if is the correct one. What am I doing wrong?

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message != '!d bump':
         await message.delete()
```

Comment: You want `message.content`; `message` is a Message object, which will alway be != to a string

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a `Message` instance to a string, to get the actual content of the message use the `content` attribute

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content != '!d bump':
         await message.delete()
```